# How to find duplicate directories

Tags: bash, perl

Let create some testing directory tree:

```
#!/bin/bash

top="./testdir"
[[ -e "$top" ]] && { echo "$top already exists!" >&2; exit 1; }

mkfile() { printf "%s\n" $(basename "$1") > "$1"; }

mkdir -p "$top"/d1/d1{1,2}
mkdir -p "$top"/d2/d1some/d12copy
mkfile "$top/d1/d12/a"
mkfile "$top/d1/d12/b"
mkfile "$top/d2/d1some/d12copy/a"
mkfile "$top/d2/d1some/d12copy/b"
mkfile "$top/d2/x"
mkfile "$top/z"
```

The structure is: `find testdir \( -type d -printf "%p/\n" , -type f -print \)`

```
testdir/
testdir/d1/
testdir/d1/d11/
testdir/d1/d12/
testdir/d1/d12/a
testdir/d1/d12/b
testdir/d2/
testdir/d2/d1some/
testdir/d2/d1some/d12copy/
testdir/d2/d1some/d12copy/a
testdir/d2/d1some/d12copy/b
testdir/d2/x
testdir/z
```

I need find the duplicate **directories**, but I need consider only files (e.g. I should ignore (sub)directories without files). So, from the above test-tree the wanted result is:

```
duplicate directories:
testdir/d1
testdir/d2/d1some
```

because in both (sub)trees are only two identical files `a` and `b`. (and several directories, without files).

Of course, I could `md5deep -Zr .`, also could walk the whole tree using `perl` script (using [File::Find](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find)+[Digest::MD5](https://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::MD5) or using [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) or like.) and calculate the file's md5-digests, but this doesn't helps for finding the duplicate **directories**... :(

Any idea how to do this? Honestly, I haven't any idea.

**EDIT**

- I don't need working `code`. (I'm able to code myself)
- I "just" need some ideas "how to approach" the solution of the problem. :)

**Edit2**

The rationale behind - why need this: I have approx 2.5 TB data copied from many external HDD's as a result of wrong backup-strategy. E.g. over the years, the whole `$HOME` dirs are copied into (many different) external HDD's. Many sub-directories has the same content, but they're in different paths. So, now I trying to eliminate the same-content directories.

And I need do this **by directories**, because here are directories, which has some duplicates files, but not all. Let say:

```
/some/path/project1/a
/some/path/project1/b
```

and

```
/some/path/project2/a
/some/path/project2/x
```

e.g. the `a` is a duplicate file (not only the name, but by the content too) - but it is needed for the both projects. So i want keep the `a` in both directories - even if they're duplicate files. Therefore me looking for a "logic" how to find duplicate directories.

Comment: Do you need to find directories matching one known directory, or you want to list directories when 2 or more are identical (according to your need to match only file) ?

Comment: You can sort filenames and build string concatenating filenames. Once string match then compare content using `diff`

Comment: Take a look here https://superuser.com/questions/909731/how-to-replace-all-duplicate-files-with-hard-links

Comment: more specifically, https://superuser.com/a/969355/68164 . Using an existing tool for a complex problem like this makes sense, but you might do well to set up a small complex test and make sure you get the results you need. Good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately, all above tools (if I got the answer right) finds the duplicate **files** and not duplicate **directories**. But, going to read more deeply. ;)

Comment: Wondering about the close-vote. According to the [help] questions about: _a specific programming problem_ or _a software algorithm_ are allowed here. This question is about the algorithm. So, would be nice to know, why the close-vote.

Comment: Rather than actually delete the files, you could use `printf "/bin/rm $deleteCandidate\n"` to generate a list of candidates to delete. If the results are very close to what you need, you can save output as a file, manually delete the `rm` records for files you want to keep, then run `sh < rmList.txt`. (just an idea, not easy to reliably do what you want, but if you can reduce the unneeded dupes by 2/3s then that is a big win). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter of course, i will be happy if i could **identify** 2/3 of duplicate directories. Unfortunately, currently i know only how to identify duplicate files - and not the whole directories. (having problem calculate the recursive the digest for thousands files in thousands of dirs). So, nice idea - but first I need **find** the duplicate **folders** first. :) Thanks anyway for the comment.

Comment: Based on file membership, I can see how `testdir/d2/d1some/d12copy/` is a duplicate of `testdir/d1/d12/`, but I don't see that `testdir/d1` , `testdir/d2/d1some` are duplicates. Can you explain, or improve your sample expected output? (I'm heading out for some family stuff soon, so won't be able to help until later). Good luck.

Comment: Also, I'm guessing that down vote appeared before your edits. I think some people have greasemonkey filters that eliminate downvoted Qs, so when they reread, they're not looking at the same "bad" problem again. (this doesn't apply to you, but given the tidal wave of bad Qs here, after a while I understand if long-term readers want to improve what they read). Good luck!

Comment: @shellter As I already said: _because in both (sub)trees are only two identical files `a` and `b`._ e.g. if you find all files in the `testdir/d1` you find _only_ two files: `a` and `b`. Also, if you will find all files `testdir/d2/d1some` you will find that here are _only_ the _same_ two files (although if in the different tree structure). So, same two files (and no other files) in two trees - e.g. the trees should be taken as identical. (Also, when me saying identical files I mean identical by their content, not by their name). It not as simple as "check this answer", like in the comments :D

Comment: Yes, I had hoped I was clear that I was beyond ""check this answer", as I understand your problem better, but I don't your sample data supports your expected output. How can you expect a system to recognize `testdir/d2/d1some/` as the correct answer when the duplicates are in a differently named subdir, i.e. `testdir/d2/d1some/d12**copy**`. This is why I think ` testdir/d2/d1some/d12copy/ is a duplicate of testdir/d1/d12/` . .. .

Comment: In any case, you'll can create an associative arr like `files["testdir/d2/d1some/d12copy/"]="a","b" and then you can loop thru testing each dir set and print just the key when you find a match. Time for bed. Will hope that you get some help overnight, or that I can spare some more time on this. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Some key points:

- If I understand right (from your comment, where you said: *"(Also, when me saying identical files I mean identical by their content, not by their name)"* , you want find duplicate directories, e.g. where their content is exactly the same as in some other directory, **regardless of the file-names**.
- for this you must calculate some checksum or digest for the files. Identical digest = identical file. (with great probability). :) As you already said, the `md5deep -Zr -of /top/dir` is a good starting point.
- I added the `-of`, because for such job you don't want calculate the contents of the symlinks-targets, or other special files like fifo - just plain files.
- calculating the `md5` for each file in 2.5TB tree, sure will take few hours of work, unless you have very fast machine. The `md5deep` runs a thread for each cpu-core. So, while it runs, you can make some scripts.
- Also, consider run the `md5deep` as `sudo`, because it could be frustrating if after a long run-time you will get some error-messages about unreadable files, only because you forgot to change the files-ownerships...(Just a note) :) :)

For the "how to":

- For comparing "directories" you need calculate some "directory-digest", for easy compare and finding duplicates.
- The one most important thing is realize the following key points:

  - you could exclude directories, where are files with unique digests. If the file is unique, e.g. has not any duplicates, that's mean that is pointless checking it's directory. Unique file in some directory means, that the directory is unique too. So, the script should ignore every directory where are files with unique `MD5` digests (from the `md5deep`'s output.)
  - You don't need calculate the "directory-digest" from the files itself. (as you trying it in [your followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43562195/632407)). It is enough to calculate the "directory digest" using the already calculated md5 for the files, *just must ensure* that you sort them first!

e.g. for example if your directory `/path/to/some` containing only two files `a` and `b` and

```
if file "a" has md5 : 0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661
and file "b" has md5: 92eb5ffee6ae2fec3ad71c777531578f
```

you can calculate the "directory-digest" from the above file-digests, e.g. using the `Digest::MD5` you could do:

```
perl -MDigest::MD5=md5_hex -E 'say md5_hex(sort qw( 92eb5ffee6ae2fec3ad71c777531578f 0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661))'
```

and will get `3bc22fb7aaebe9c8c5d7de312b876bb8` as your "directory-digest". The sort is crucial(!) here, because the same command, but without the sort:

```
perl -MDigest::MD5=md5_hex -E 'say md5_hex(qw( 92eb5ffee6ae2fec3ad71c777531578f 0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661))'
```

produces: `3a13f2408f269db87ef0110a90e168ae`.

Note, even if the above digests aren't the digests of your files, but they're will be unique for every directory with different files and will be the same for the identical files. (because identical files, has identical md5 file-digest). The sorting ensures, that you will calculate the digest always in the same order, e.g. if some other directory will contain two files

```
file "aaa" has md5 : 92eb5ffee6ae2fec3ad71c777531578f
file "bbb" has md5 : 0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661
```

using the above `sort and md5` you will again get: `3bc22fb7aaebe9c8c5d7de312b876bb8` - e.g. the directory containing same files as above...

So, in such way you can calculate some "directory-digest" for every directory you have and could be ensured that if you get another directory digest `3bc22fb7aaebe9c8c5d7de312b876bb8` thats means: this directory has exactly the above two files `a` and `b` (even if their names are different).

This method is fast, because you will calculate the "directory-digests" only from small 32bytes strings, so you avoids excessive multiple file-digest-caclulations.

The final part is easy now. Your final data should be in form:

```
3a13f2408f269db87ef0110a90e168ae /some/directory
16ea2389b5e62bc66b873e27072b0d20 /another/directory
3a13f2408f269db87ef0110a90e168ae /path/to/other/directory
```

so, from this is easy to get: the

`/some/directory` and the `/path/to/other/directory` are identical, because they has identical "directory-digests".

Hm... All the above is only a few lines long perl script. Probably would be faster to write here directly the perl-script as the above long textual answer - but, you said - you don't want code... :) :)

Answer (score 3):

A traversal can identify directories which are duplicates in the sense you describe. I take it that this is: if all files in a directory are equal to all files of another then their paths are duplicates.

Find all files in each directory and form a string with their names. You can concatenate the names with a comma, say (or some other sequence that is certainly not in any names). This is to be compared. Prepend the path to this string, so to identify directories.

Comparison can be done for instance by populating a hash with keys being strings with filenames and path their values. Once you find that a key already exists you can check the content of files, and add the path to the list of duplicates.

The strings with path don't have to be actually formed, as you can build the hash and dupes list during the traversal.  Having the full list first allows for other kinds of accounting, if desired.

This is altogether very little code to write.

An example. Let's say that you have

```
dir1/subdir1/{a,b}  # duplicates (files 'a' and 'b' are considered equal)
dir2/subdir2/{a,b}
```

and

```
proj1/subproj1/{a,b,X}  # NOT duplicates, since there are different files
proj2/subproj2/{a,b,Y}
```

The above prescription would give you strings

```
'dir1/subdir1/a,b',
'dir2/subdir2/a,b',
'proj1/subproj1/a,b,X',
'proj2/subproj2/a,b,Y';
```

where the (sub)string `'a,b'` identifies `dir1/subdir1` and `dir2/subdir2` as duplicates.

I don't see how you can avoid a traversal to build a system that accounts for all files.

---

The procedure above is the first step, not handling directories with files *and* subdirectories.

Consider

```
   dirA/          dirB/
a b sdA/       a X sdB/
    c d            c d
```

Here the paths `dirA/sdA/` and `dirB/sdB/` are duplicates by the problem description but the whole `dirA/` and `dirB/` are distinct. This isn't shown in the question but I'd expect it to be of interest.

The procedure from the first part can be modified for this. Iterate through directories, forming a path component at every step. Get all files in each, and all subdirectories (if none we are done). Append the comma-separated file list to the path component (`/sdA/`). So the representation of the above is

```
'dirA/sdA,a,b/c,d',  'dirB/sdB,a,X/c,d'
```

For each file-list substring (`c,d`) found to already exist we can check its path against the existing one, component by component. Now a hash with keys like `c,d` won't do since this example has the same file-list for distinct hierarchies, but a modified (or other) data structure is needed.

---

Finally, there may be  more subdirectories parallel to `sdA` (say `sdA2`). We care only for its own path, but except for the parallel files (`a,b`, in that component of the path `dirA/sdaA2,a,b/`). So keep in mind all bottom-level file-lists (`c,d`) with their paths and, if file-lists are equal and paths are of same length, check whether their paths have `a,b` file-lists equal in each path component.

I don't know whether this is a workable solution for you, but I'd expect "near-duplicates" to be rare -- the backup is either a duplicate or not. So there may not be much need to handle futher edge-cases in complex sprawling hierarchies.  This procedure should be at least a useful pre-selection mechanism, that would greatly reduce the need for further work.

This assumes that equal file-names very likely indicate equal files. A part of that is my expectation that if a file was even just renamed it still cannot be considered a duplicate. If this is not so this approach won't work and one would need something along the lines of the [answer by jm666](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43573478/4653379).

Comment: He said ( deeply hidden in comments :( ): _(Also, when me saying identical files I mean identical by their content, not by their name)_. So, compare by names aren't enough...

Comment: @jm666 Right, I saw that (slightly different than in your quote).  I take it that it means that equal names do indicate equal files.  But this approach does fully rely on equal files having equal names, as you say.  I added a note on that.

Comment: @cajwine  I don't know how suitable this approach is for you, but just to let you know -- I added another section to cover a case that was missing.

Answer (score 1):

I make a tool which searches duplicate folders.
https://github.com/un1t/dirdups

```
dirdups testdir -i 1
```

**-i 1** option consider folders as duplicates if they have at least 1 file in common. Without this option default value is 10.

In your case it will find the following directories:

```
testdir/d1/d12/
testdir/d2/d1some/d12copy/
```