# Reuse calculated md5 (or any other checksum)

Tags: perl

Trying to compute incremental `md5` digest for all files in deep directory trees, but I'm unable to "reuse" the already calculated digest.

Here is my test-code:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Digest::MD5;
use Path::Tiny;

# create some test-files in the tempdir
my @filenames = qw(a b);
my $testdir = Path::Tiny->tempdir;
$testdir->child($_)->spew($_) for @filenames; #create 2 files

dirmd5($testdir, @filenames);
exit;

sub dirmd5 {
    my($dir, @files) = @_;

    my $dirctx = Digest::MD5->new;  #the md5 for the whole directory

    for my $fname (@files) {

        # calculate the md5 for one file
        my $filectx = Digest::MD5->new;
        my $fd = $dir->child($fname)->openr_raw;
        $filectx->addfile($fd);
        close $fd;
        say "md5 for $fname  : ", $filectx->clone->hexdigest;

        # want somewhat "add" the above file-md5 to the directory md5    
        # this not work - even if the $filectx isn't reseted (note the "clone" above)
        #$dirctx->add($filectx);

        # works adding the file as bellow,
        # but this calculating the md5 again
        # e.g. for each file the calculation is done two times...
        # once for the file-alone (above)
        # and second time for the directory
        # too bad if case of many and large files. ;(
        # especially, if i want calculate the md5sum for the whole directory trees
        $fd = $dir->child($fname)->openr_raw;
        $dirctx->addfile($fd);
        close $fd;
    }
    say "md5 for dir: ", $dirctx->hexdigest;
}
```

The above prints:

```
md5 for a  : 0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661
md5 for b  : 92eb5ffee6ae2fec3ad71c777531578f
md5 for dir: 187ef4436122d1cc2f40dc2b92f0eba0
```

which is correct, but unfortunately inefficient way. (see the comments).

Reading [the docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::MD5), I didn't find any way reuse the already calculated md5. e.g. as the above `$dirctx->add($filectx);`. Probably it is not possible.

Exists any way for check-summing which allows somewhat reuse the already calculated checksums, so, I would be able calculate the checksums/digests for the whole directory trees without the need calculate the digest multiple times for each file?

Ref: trying somewhat solve [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43560796/how-to-find-duplicate-directories)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is nothing that relates `MD5(initial data)` and `MD5(new data)` to `MD5(initial data + new data)` because the *position* of the data in the stream matters as well as its *value*. Otherwise it wouldn't be a very useful error check as `aba`, `aab` and `baa` would all have the same checksum

If the files are small enough you could do read each one into memory and use that copy to add the data to both digests. That would avoid reading twice from mass storage

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.014;
use warnings 'all';

use Digest::MD5;
use Path::Tiny;

# create some test-files in the tempdir
my @filenames = qw(a b);
my $testdir   = Path::Tiny->tempdir;
$testdir->child($_)->spew($_) for @filenames; # create 2 files

dirmd5($testdir, @filenames);

sub dirmd5 {
    my ($dir, @files) = @_;

    my $dir_ctx = Digest::MD5->new;  #the md5 for the whole directory

    for my $fname ( @files ) {

        my $data = $dir->child($fname)->slurp_raw;

        # calculate the md5 for one file
        my $file_md5 = Digest::MD5->new->add($data)->hexdigest;
        say "md5 for $fname  : $file_md5";

        $dir_ctx->add($data);
    }

    my $dir_md5 = $dir_ctx->hexdigest;
    say "md5 for dir: $dir_md5";
}
```

If the files are huge then the only optimisation left is to avoid reopening the same file and instead rewind it back to the start before reading it a second time

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.014;
use warnings 'all';

use Digest::MD5;
use Path::Tiny;
use Fcntl ':seek';

# create some test-files in the tempdir
my @filenames = qw(a b);
my $testdir   = Path::Tiny->tempdir;
$testdir->child($_)->spew($_) for @filenames; # create 2 files

dirmd5($testdir, @filenames);

sub dirmd5 {
    my ($dir, @files) = @_;

    my $dir_ctx = Digest::MD5->new;  # The digest for the whole directory

    for my $fname ( @files ) {

        my $fh = $dir->child($fname)->openr_raw;

        # The digest for just the current file
        my $file_md5 = Digest::MD5->new->addfile($fh)->hexdigest;
        say "md5 for $fname  : $file_md5";

        seek $fh, 0, SEEK_SET;
        $dir_ctx->addfile($fh);
    }

    my $dir_md5 = $dir_ctx->hexdigest;
    say "md5 for dir: $dir_md5";
}
```

Comment: Ah so. Then it is pointless to trying calculate the digest for the whole directory trees with multiple nested directories, because i will need calculate the digest for each file again and again for each directory "above"... ah... :( need figure out some other "logic" for the [duplicate directory trees](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43560796/869025) problem" . Thank you.

Comment: @cajwine: There's no need for that. Just keep a digest alive for each file and every one of its ancestor directories in the tree. The data in any file must be added to the digest of each ancestor directory. It's pretty much the same as working out the size of every directory in a tree, except that you can't just add the values for the children together at the end.